Group spark dataframe column values based on variable scale
I have a dataframe with survey results. Each question has varying numeric scale from 4 - 6. I would like to bucket results based on the scale with the highest two answers being good results and the bottom 2 being poor. Everything else will be average. The results dataframe looks like this
question     answer
question_1   1 
question_1   4 
question_1   6
question_2   2
question_2   4 

I would like to group the results to the dataframe becomes like this
question    answer  meaning
question_1   1       poor
question_1   4       average
question_1   6       good
question_2   2       poor
question_2   4       good

The meaning of the survey score changes based on the scale. For example, question_1 is on a scale of 6, so 4 would be average and question_2 is on a scale of 5, so 4 would be good.

Assuming you already have the scale of each question, then you can do a simple join and math condition
Input
val scale=spark.read.json(Seq("""
[
    {"question": "question_1", "scale": 6},
    {"question": "question_2", "scale": 4}
]""").toDS())

val df=spark.read.json(Seq("""
[
    {"question": "question_1", "answer": 1},
    {"question": "question_1", "answer": 4},
    {"question": "question_1", "answer": 6},
    {"question": "question_2", "answer": 2},
    {"question": "question_2", "answer": 4}
]""").toDS())

Logic
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.join(scale, "question")
  .withColumn("meaning", 
    when(col("answer") <= 2, "poor")
    .otherwise(when(col("answer") > (col("scale") - 2), "good").otherwise("average"))
  ).show()

Output
+----------+------+-----+-------+
|  question|answer|scale|meaning|
+----------+------+-----+-------+
|question_1|     1|    6|   poor|
|question_1|     4|    6|average|
|question_1|     6|    6|   good|
|question_2|     2|    4|   poor|
|question_2|     4|    4|   good|
+----------+------+-----+-------+

Since you have the scale for each question, you adjust the rules to consider each meaning for each question if needed!
